# java.util.Calendar returning wrong values on calender.add(date,number)

Tags: java, date, calendar

Hi i'm trying to get the date which is current date minus 4

Today current date is **Tue Nov 04 16:35:34 IST 2014**

what i'm doing is

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, days);
System.out.println("new date "+" "+cal.get(cal.YEAR)+" "+cal.get(cal.MONTH)+" "+cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

This is the output i'm getting
new date  2014 9 31 (but the expected is 2014 10 31)

I don't know what went wrong. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Don't format dates like that - use `SimpleDateFormat`. The months in java.util.Calendar are 0-based...

Comment: Please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Month is Calendar API start in 0. So January is 0, February is 1, etc...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH